# Use value1 and value2 for filterBy in datatable Primefaces Filter

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Hi I have problem with Filter in Primeface Datatable.I dont know how can I use FlterBy wit my Code.
my  xhtml file:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblHaupt" 
                value="#{hauptMB.myList}"

                rowKey="#{myList.id}"
                sortBy="time" 
                sortOrder="descending"          

                widgetVar="carsTable"
                filteredValue="#{hauptMB.filteredmyList}">`



               <p:column  headerText="Typ"  filterBy="????????????????????"  filterMatchMode="contains">
               <h:outputText value="#{myList.requestId == null ? value1 : value2 />
               </p:column>
```

what can I writen ,where ??????????????

i want use value1 and value2 for filterBy not one column of mylist.because it is not in mylist.

thanks.If anyone can help me out here, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Either use a filterFunction or use a lazyDataModel.